# How to replace '-' in value of aria-labelledby with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace

When doing an accessibility test I have a violation that the value of aria-labelledby attr is not correctly set up, there is a '-' which i want to replace with a space, so it is conforming the rules.

The current code is;

```
<div id="0_48_gbt_444" class="mx-radiogroup" aria-labelledby="0_48_gbt_444-label" role="radiogroup">
   <div class="radio"><input type="radio" id="0_48_gbt_444_0" name="0_48_gbt_444" value="PCT"><label for="0_48_gbt_444_0">Postal Code Targeting</label></div>
</div>
```

I need the attr  like this ('-' is replaced with ' ';

```
aria-labelledby="0_48_gbt_444 label"
```

I have tried the following, but did not work;

```
$('aria-labelledby').val(function (i, value) {
    return value.replace('-', '');
});
```

How can I replace/overwrite it like suggested?

Comment: `aria-labelledby` is an attribute - you need to find the elements that has that attribute and use a replace on the attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your selector is looking for `<aria-labelledby></aria-labelledby>` and not element with that attribute
2. You should set attribute, not return something:

```js
$('[aria-labelledby]').val(function () {
    let newValue = $(this).attr('aria-labelledby').replace('-', '');
    $(this).attr('aria-labelledby', newValue);
});
```